# $\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)d\lambda(x,y)=\int_\mathbb R\int_\mathbb R f(x,y)d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a measurable function. Is ist true that 
$\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)d\lambda(x,y)=\int_\mathbb R\int_\mathbb R f(x,y)d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)$.
I think it is only true if $f$ is non-negative but I didn't found a counterexample.

Comment: You quoted the relevant theorem that gives you sufficient conditions when this is true. $f$ can be negative as long as its absolutely integrable then the theorem is true. Also you can check whether it's absolutely integrable directly by using this theorem (this is Tonelli theorem); then if you find the integral is finite you can apply Fubini theorem directly to $f$ (without absolute values).

Comment: But only with the condition "$f$ is measurable" this is false, but if $f$ is integrable this is true, right?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is merely measurable then this can be false and there are standard counterexamples. I'm sure you have encountered such counterexamples with discrete infinite sums; an infinite sum is an integral with respect to the counting measure, hence you have your counterexample.

Comment: To be clear, if $f$ is merely measurable, then $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}f(x,y)\,d\lambda(x,y)$ is a-priori a meaningless symbol. Finding a 'counter-example' to Fubini means finding a measurable function $f$ for which the iterated integrals both exist but are unequal, and yes in this case, there are such functions (for which necessarily $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}|f(x,y)|\,d\lambda(x,y)=0$).

Comment: ^ I meant $=\infty$ of course in the last equality